# VS Code turned .ipynb file to binary and cannot open

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was working on a project in python in MS VSCODE and saved a file. When returning to it, the file wouldn't open in the editor and claims

> "the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding"

Any ideas or help on how to resolve this? And also why this happened? I cannot find any helpful threads any where.

Comment: Did you edit this file anywhere else? And I assume this is a `.ipynb` file?

Comment: The same happened to me today using the intelliJ Idea IDE. I was running Jupyter in a Docker container and at one point my computer hung it self up and I had to restart. When trying to open the notebook again, I realized it had become a binary file. Now I'm desperately looking for a way to re-convert it, otherwise I will have to rewrite a lot of code. Have you been working with Docker as well by any chance?

Comment: @Nima hey, I was not in docker unfortunately. The only probable cause I could figure out was my local computing resources ran out, and had to move to cloud resources - I’m not sure if this suits your case. Sorry about that, I know the pain

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KyleWalden! Luckily, after I recovered from the first shock, I realized there was a backup in `.ipynb_checkpoints`, so I was able to recover the code. But I'm still wondering what could have caused this and how to avoid it in the future. If someone who has an idea finds this thread, please share.